# php 5.5.1: opcahe and intl not work

Tags: php, intl, opcache

**I installed php 5.5.1 on centos 5.8 with the following setting**

> './configure' '--prefix=/usr/local/php' '--with-libdir=lib64'
>   '--with-config-file-path=/etc/php/php.d' '--disable-debug'
>   '--with-pic' '--disable-rpath' '--without-pear' '--with-bz2'
>   '--with-curl' '--enable-gd-native-ttf' '--with-gdbm' '--with-gettext'
>   '--with-gmp' '--with-iconv' '--with-openssl' '--with-pspell'
>   '--with-zlib' '--with-layout=GNU' '--enable-exif' '--enable-ftp'
>   '--enable-sockets' '--enable-sysvsem' '--enable-sysvshm'
>   '--enable-sysvmsg' '--enable-wddx' '--with-kerberos' '--enable-shmop'
>   '--enable-calendar' '--with-mysqli' '--with-apxs2' '--with-mysql'
>   '--with-gd' '--with-jpeg-dir=/usr' '--disable-dba'
>   '--without-unixODBC' '--enable-mbstring' '--with-pdo-mysql'
>   '--enable-zip' '--with-mcrypt' '--enable-soap' '--enable-opcache'

**php.ini**:

```
zend_extension=opcache.so   
opcache.memory_consumption=256    
opcache.interned_strings_buffer=8    
opcache.max_accelerated_files=4000    
opcache.revalidate_freq=60   
opcache.fast_shutdown=1   
opcache.enable_cli=1   
opcache.enable=On   
extension=/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/intl.so
```

php doesn't show any error during installation but **opcache** and **intl** is not appear in output of phpinfo()   (httpd restarted)

what is the problem here? please help me to fix it.

Comment: Is `/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/intl.so` the correct path to `intl.so`? The config options seem to indicate it'd be under `/usr/local/php` somewhere. You may also need to give a full path to `opcache.so`.

Comment: full path is still not work

Comment: Have you checked with `phpinfo()` that it's using the `php.ini` you think it is?